# I am getting an error in opencv ,but i am giving the correct and full path to the harcascades files and its a realtimelive face detection

Tags: macos, opencv, face-recognition

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "faceDetection.py", line 21, in 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Comment: It says the src.empty() means it is unable to read or capture frames .

Answer (score 0):

The path to your input image is incorrect. Double check that the path is correct and if it is, check if the image isn't corrupted by opening it up in an image viewer.